# Customizing a form with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a already created form using bootstrap but I would like to customizing it by adding class and such. I found nothing on the docs.

Here is the normal form in HTML:

```
<form id="form" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Pseudo</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="xX_Pseudo_Cool_93_Xx" name="form[username]" id="emailSignUp" type="email" required="required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="email@example.com" name="form[email]" id="emailSignUp" type="email" required="required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" name="password" id="password" type="password" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="password">Confirmer le mot de passe</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Confirmer le mot de passe" name="passwordConfirm" id="passwordConfirm" type="password" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input id="term" type="checkbox" required>
                                En créant votre compte, vous acceptez nos <a href="{{ path('policy') }}">termes et conditions & politique de confidentialité</a>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="btnsignup" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 127px;">S'inscrire</button>
                    </form>
```

Here is the form that actually works but it doesn't have anything and it's with Symfony:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.username) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second) }}

    <button type="submit">Register!</button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

So, what I would like to do is to actually customize the Symfony form based on my HTML.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: __Everyting__ is already described on [symfony site](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html).

Comment: @u_mulder I'm sorry, I don't know if it's me but I don't see anything that says something about adding class and such

Comment: @MikeLévy, are you using Symfony Forms? See https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Comment: If want symfony to set the bootstrap classes automaticly you can use its "formtheme" described here https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/bootstrap4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the form like in the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/forms.html

With a form class or a using the form builder in the controller (the form class is a better option).

Then, when defining the fields use the code below:

```
->add('subtitle', 'text',
           array(
               'label'          => 'Subtitle',
               'attr'           => array(
                   'placeholder' => 'The subtitle',
                   'class' => 'form-control'
               ),
               'required'       => false,
           )
```

You can specify in the `attr` section of the options the `class` key that will render the class in the html file.

An alternative is set the class in the template. For that, instead of call `form_row(form.username)` you call the render function only with the fields passing the attributes like below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.username, null, {"label_attr": {"class": "col-sm-2 control-label" }}) }}

    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(form.username, {"attr": {"class": "form-control" } }) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

More information here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Since symfony already ships with a complete bootstrap form theme. This way works but is a lot more work.